# Meaning of "Attended Party" multiplier

Tags: rimworld

After attending a party, pawns are given an "Attended Party" mood boost. I've noticed though that there's a multiplier next to the attribute, like "Attended Party x4", and they get a mood boost that seems to be around 75% the value of the multiplier (they get a 3 point mood boost with a "x4" multiplier).

I know the multiplier isn't how many parties they've attended because I know my guys haven't thrown, for example, 4 parties within 10 days (the expiry period of the buff). It seems to be a "quality" indicator.

What effects the multiplier? Number of social interactions? Time spent at the party? And is there a reliable way to ensure higher multiples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **time spent at the party**.

I've interrupted parties by sending a few of the hauler monkeys to bring the harvested food in, and they had less "attended party" multipliers.

I don't know the exact numbers (max multiplier for full attendance), but it seems like the multipliers tick regularly during the party.

Comment: A new thought stack is added to all guests every 600 ticks (10 seconds of real time, or about 15 minutes of in-game time). They can have a maximum of 10 stacks. The first stack is worth 1 mood point, each additional is worth 3/4 of a point.

Comment: @Cadence: Thanks for adding concrete numbers :)